# Возможен ли асинхронный сервер RabbitMQ?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, rpc

Рассмотрел шаблон работы RabbitMQ(RPC) [принцип работы описан тут](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-dotnet.html). Как я понял единственная возможность как то распараллелить обработку запросов это запустить несколько "серверов".
Я подписываюсь на событие "Received" объекта EventingBasicConsumer и в обработке этого события формируется ответ клиенту (других способов организовать передачу данных используя RabbitMQ я пока не знаю). И если ответ формируется долго этот метод передачи сообщений не доступен
 Хотелось бы узнать есть ли возможность именно асинхронной обработки очереди?

Comment: запросов чего и куда? какого рода обработка очереди?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Не хотелось бы тут пример дублировать из ссылки с вопроса Запускаю сервер. Делаю RPC клиент, вызываю функцию на сервере (не знаю сколь долго она может выполняться) хочу чтобы сервер был доступен другим клиентам, пока  ответ на "долгую" функцию еще не сформирован.

Comment: просто вопрос звучит странно *Возможен ли асинхронный сервер RabbitMQ?*, но как я понимаю вас не **RabbitMQ** интересует, а ваш собственный сервер, который использует **RabbitMQ**. я прав?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman возможно я могу изъясняться по дилетантски. Я не глубоко разобрался с протоколом AMQP, и с принципами работы самого RabbitMQ. Но я задаю вопрос в контексте .net приложения которое использует RabbitMQ. Я подписываюсь на событие "Received" объекта EventingBasicConsumer и в обработке этого события формируется ответ клиенту (других способов организовать передачу данных используя RabbitMQ я пока не знаю). И если ответ формируется долго этот метод передачи сообщений не доступен. Как сделать асинхронный сервер(допустим по http) мне известно, опять же в контексте .net

Comment: добавьте всю эту информацию в вопрос. вам надо просто создать сервер который может работать с **RabbitMQ**.

Comment: Да просто тредов-подписчиков наплодить и все.

Comment: @etki да, к этому и пришел)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как написал пользователь [etki](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/16095/etki). Добавляя новые потоки, сервер RabbitMQ работает асинхронно. Ниже приведет измененный пример сервера из мануала RabbitMQ(ссылка в вопросе), клиент остается такой же как и в примере.

```
    public  class RPCServer
{
    private static Thread _thread1;
    private static Thread _thread2;
    public static void Main()
    {
        CreateFewThreads();

    }

    private static void CreateFewThreads()
    {
        _thread1 = new Thread(delegate() { CreateConnetction(); });
        _thread1.Start();
        _thread2 = new Thread(delegate() { CreateConnetction(); });
        _thread2.Start();
    }
    public static void CreateConnetction()
    {

        var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };
        using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
        {
            channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "rpc_queue", durable: false,
              exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: null);
            channel.BasicQos(0, 1, false);
            var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer();
            channel.DefaultConsumer = consumer;
            channel.BasicConsume(queue: "rpc_queue",
              noAck: false, consumer: consumer);
            Console.WriteLine(" [x] Awaiting RPC requests");

            consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
            {
                WaitCallback waite = new System.Threading.WaitCallback(AcyncResponse);
                WaitCallbacObject wco = new WaitCallbacObject() { ea = ea, channel = channel };
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(waite, wco);

            };

            Console.WriteLine(" Press [enter] to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    private static int fib(int n)
    {
        if (n == 0 || n == 1)
        {
            return n;
        }

        return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
    }


    private static void AcyncResponse(object state)
    {
        WaitCallbacObject waitCallbackObject = state as WaitCallbacObject;
        var ea = waitCallbackObject.ea;
        var channel = waitCallbackObject.channel;

        string response = null;

        var body = ea.Body;
        var props = ea.BasicProperties;
        var replyProps = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
        replyProps.CorrelationId = props.CorrelationId;

        try
        {
            var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
            int n = int.Parse(message);
            Console.WriteLine(" [.] fib({0})", message);
            response = fib(n).ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" [.] " + e.Message);
            response = "";
        }
        finally
        {
            var responseBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response);
            channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "", routingKey: props.ReplyTo,
              basicProperties: replyProps, body: responseBytes);
            channel.BasicAck(deliveryTag: ea.DeliveryTag,
              multiple: false);
        }
    }
}
public class WaitCallbacObject
{
    public BasicDeliverEventArgs ea { get; set; }
    public IModel channel { get; set; }
    public WaitCallbacObject() { }
}
```

Comment: Кроме просто "наплодить тредов-клиентов" вы еще всегда можете имплементировать  producer-consumer в своем коде и сделать клиент максимально тонким за счет передачи заданий в очередь, которую будут разбирать другие потоки.

Comment: @etki спасибо обязательно попробую!